# Android JobScheduler detect connectivity state changed

Tags: android, android-networking, android-7.0-nougat, android-jobscheduler, jobservice

I want to detect connectivity state changed on Android Nougat. I read in Android documentation that is not possible to receive `CONNECTIVITY_ACTION`. So I attempt to use `JobScheduler` to get connectivity state changed. I did it in this way.

I create `JobService` like that:

```
public class NetworkStateScheduler extends JobService {
    private Messenger jobServiceMessenger;
    public static final String TAG = "NetworkStateScheduler";

    @Override
    public boolean onStartJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStartJob");
        sendMessage(jobParameters.getJobId(), NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onStopJob(JobParameters jobParameters) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onStopJob");
        sendMessage(jobParameters.getJobId(), NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        jobServiceMessenger = intent.getParcelableExtra(MESSENGER_INTENT_KEY);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(new Intent(MainActivity.START_SERVICE_FILTER));

        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    private void sendMessage(int messageID, Object params) {
        if (jobServiceMessenger == null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Service is bound, not started. There's no callback to send a message to.");
            return;
        }

        Message m = Message.obtain();
        m.what = messageID;
        m.obj = params;
        try {
            jobServiceMessenger.send(m);
        } catch (RemoteException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Error passing service object back to activity.");
        }
    }
}
```

I think it looks simple, when `JobService` is started I provide `jobServiceMessenger` to communication `JobService` with `MainActivity`.

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static final String MESSENGER_INTENT_KEY = "IncomingMessage";
    public static final String START_SERVICE_FILTER = "start.service";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                Log.i(NetworkStateScheduler.TAG, "Service started");
                scheduleJob();
            }
        }, new IntentFilter(START_SERVICE_FILTER));
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, NetworkStateScheduler.class);
        intent.putExtra(MESSENGER_INTENT_KEY, new Messenger(new IncomingMessageHandler()));
        startService(intent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        stopService(new Intent(this, NetworkStateScheduler.class));
        super.onStop();
    }

    public void scheduleJob() {
        Log.i(NetworkStateScheduler.TAG, "Scheduling job");

        JobScheduler jobScheduler =
                (JobScheduler) getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        jobScheduler.cancelAll();

        JobInfo jobInfo = new JobInfo.Builder(1,
                new ComponentName(this, NetworkStateScheduler.class))
                .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
                .setBackoffCriteria(0, JobInfo.BACKOFF_POLICY_LINEAR)
                .build();

        jobScheduler.schedule(jobInfo);
    }

    private static class IncomingMessageHandler extends Handler {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            NetworkInfo.State state = (NetworkInfo.State) msg.obj;
            Log.d(NetworkStateScheduler.TAG, "state " + state);
        }
    }
}
```

In this part of code I added simple broadcast receiver to know when JobService started, because I have to know to run my Job and detect connectivity state.

Right now it works in this way: App started. Service is starting and triggered job to run. If connection is established then `onStartJob` method from `JobService` is called. When connection broke then method `onStopJob` is called. It looks like JobService works properly because whenever I connect or disconnect wifi on the device I got message from `onStartJob` or `onStopJob`. But sometimes after couple running app that `JobService` starting but method from Service is not called. I don't know why. I don't understand why it works properly and sometime it doesn't works. It is not deterministic.

How can I fix this?
(I added service to android manifest)